# How should I avoid duplicate imports when writing a package?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm making a python package to run analyses with pandas, and I use pandas objects in most files in the package. How do I import those functions so they're usable in the package but don't clutter the namespace for a user? Say I have this directory structure:

```
MyThing/
    MyThing/
        __init__.py
        apis.py
        MyClass.py
```

where `MyClass.py` provides a class I will instantiate to process data in memory and `apis.py` has interfaces to local and remote databases. As a demonstration, say `__init__.py` contains

```py
from MyThing.MyClass import MyClass
from MyThing.apis import DBInterface
```

the contents of `MyClass.py` are

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__():
        pass
```

and `apis.py` is

```py
import pandas as pd

class DBInterface:
    
    def __init__():
        pass
```

With complete code I expect the use case to look something like this

```py
import MyThing as mt

# get some data
interface = mt.DBInterface()
some_data = interface.query(parameters)

# load it into MyThing
instance = mt.MyThing(some_data)

# add new data from another source
instance.read(filename)

# make some fancy products
instance.magic(parameters)

# update the database
interface.update_db(instance)
```

The concern I have is that `dir(mt.apis)` shows everything I've imported, meaning I can do things like make a pandas DataFrame with `df = mt.apis.pd.DataFrame()`. Is this how it's supposed to work? Should I be using `import` differently so the namespace isn't cluttered with dependencies? Should I design the package differently so the dependencies aren't available when I import `MyThing`?

Comment: I believe you are doing everything correctly. However you can remove the dependency's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is fine and how it's supposed to work and I wouldn't advise trying hard to hide your pandas import.

The solution to this `df = mt.apis.pd.DataFrame()` is: don't do that.

If there is a function or variable within `Mything.apis` that you don't want others to use, you can prefix it with a single underscore (eg. `_foo`). By convention this is understood to be for "internal use" and is not imported when you do `from Mything.apis import *`. See [this section of the PEP-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for more information about naming conventions of this sort.

If you'd like to be more explicit about what things your module exports you may define them like so `__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']`. This also makes it so that if you or someone does `from Mything.apis import *` (which is generally ill-advised anyway) they will only import `foo` and `bar`, but you should treat this as a mere suggestion, just like the leading underscore convention.